# Monitoring tool without web interface

Tags: linux, security, monitoring

I need to monitor a Linux server. I'm searching for a monitoring tool able to store system information (CPU, RAM disks usage, Apache and Postfix status, etc.) throughout the day and send an email every day with a complete report.

Every monitoring tool I saw (nagios, monit, cacti, ...) has a web interface or it opens a port enabling a client access on the server. For security reasons I need to avoid this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sar` from the `sysstat` package?

Comment: Sounds like you don't care whether the tool ***has*** a network interface; you care that any network interface that is available can be disabled.

Comment: I would write a custom made script and setup a ssh passwordless authentication to the servers I wanted to monitor. No risk of opening another port here.

Comment: thank you, i think `sysstat`  will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a tool but I'm afraid it also has a web interface. It's called SeaLion. Even after knowing your apprehension for such tools I'm still suggesting you this tool because:

1. The agent runs as an unprivileged user.
2. All data transfer takes place over SSL connection.

So this should address your security concern.

The tool has a 'daily digest' feature that sends you an email everyday reporting any of the system metrics that crosses threshold. For more information refer to their [website](https://sealion.com/). I'm currently using this tool and so far it has been a smooth run.